# Python CSV to JSON batch inquiry, how to output remaining items

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

Ok, the title is a bit confusing, so I apologize.

Basically, I'm working on a Python script that simply creates a new JSON file from the contents of a CSV file.

For the most part, the script works, but now I'm in the portion where tweeking needs to be done.

Right now, I have it set up so it'll read the contents, and create a file for every 10 items in the CSV file.

```
import csv
import json
from time import time

start = time()


def make_json(csv_path):
    data = []

    with open(csv_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvp:

        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvp)

        counter = 0

        for row in csv_reader:
            row_items = list(row.items())
            for k, v in row_items:
                if v == "":
                    del row[k]

            data.append(row)
            counter += 1

            if counter % 10 == 0:

                output = {
                    "items": data
                }

                json_path = rf'test{counter}.json'
                with open(json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as jsonp:
                    jsonp.write(json.dumps(output, indent=2))

                counter += 0
                data = []


csv_path = r'random43.csv'

make_json(csv_path)

print(f'Time taken to run: {time() - start} seconds')
```

Example of the CSV:

```
Number,First Name,Last Name
1,Marion,Maltie
2,Jesse,Christopher
3,Frank,Dixon
4,Marquerite,Holbrook
5,Justin,Houk
6,Annette,Root
7,Noreen,Marshall
8,Kathryn,Griggs
9,Tammy,Dana
10,Nicholas,Richardson
11,Katherine,Wilks
12,Jessica,Phillips
13,Alan,Woodward
```

This works fine...if the CSV files only have items within that are multiples of 10. The issue now, is what to do with the remaining items.

Example, a CSV with 40 items will kick out four files; first 10, second 20, and so on. However, if I run a CSV with 43 items (or anything not ending in zero), it'll still only push out the four files. The last three items in the file will simply be forgotten.

I'm killing myself trying to figure out how to get those last few items in their own smaller file. Any assistance to put me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: add `writing to file` code after the loop and run it if the rest is not empty

Answer (score 0):

In addition to writing in multiples of 10 during the loop, you need to write the remaining items to an output file *after* you've finished the loop.

```
for row in csv_reader:
    # do something with row

    # collect items in data
    # data.append(something)

    counter += 1
    if counter % 10 == 0:
        # write output to file
        
        data = []

# for loop ended
# If data is not empty, we have remaining items to write
if data:
    # write output to file
```

First, let's create a function called `write_json()`. For example:

```
def write_json(path, data):
    output = {"items": data}
    with open(json_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as jsonp:
        json.dump(jsonp, output, indent=2)
```

Then use the function we just defined in our code:

```
def make_json(csv_path):
    data = []
    with open(csv_path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvp:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvp)

        counter = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            row_items = list(row.items())
            for k, v in row_items:
                if v == "":
                    del row[k]

            data.append(row)
            counter += 1
            if counter % 10 == 0:
                json_path = rf'test{counter}.json'
                write_json(json_path, data)
                data = []
    
    if data:
        json_path = rf'test{counter}.json'
        write_json(json_path, data)
```